# ImageMagick: Remove 2 pixels wide lines

Tags: imagemagick

How can I remove two pixels wide lines (like the three lines in the image below) without altering the rest of the image, and repage it to its new minimum border ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is extract the alpha channel. Then use morphology close. Then put the result back into the alpha channel, then trim and save the result. In Imagemagick, that would be:

Input:

[image]

```
convert image.png \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract -morphology open octagon:2 \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
-trim +repage \
result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
convert captcha.png -morphology erode disk:2 -trim +repage result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's altering the content of the image. It's pretty good in the case of a number like this example, but for other shapes it won't work.

Comment: Sorry, I can only go by the images I can see! Maybe add some for which my suggestion fails...